# Future forms. Will / going to / Present Continuous?

Tags: grammar, future

"Congratulations! I hear yoy (get married) soon."

What form should we use in this sentence? Will / going to / Present Continuous?

Answer (score -1):

All of them, with very slightly different meanings.

> I hear you are getting married soon.

is probably the most common, and has no special meaning.

> I hear you get married soon.

is very similar - perhaps a little less emphasis on the wedding itself and more on the state of being married.

> I hear you are going to get married soon.

The focus there is perhaps more on your intention than on the future event.

> I hear you will get married soon.

This is the least likely option, but it is still possible. The "will" makes it a bit more formal, and to me there is also a distancing effect, as if the speaker is less involved with the hearer and their marriage plans.